# When I write a list to a CSV, why does it not show the columns correctly in Excel?

Tags: python, csv

The Python code I've written to turn a list into a CSV doesn't work like what I expected.

It gives me an unorganized csv file.

This is my code

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\scraping\\ddd.csv', 'w') as output_file:

    file = csv.writer(output_file)
    file.writerow(["name","age","N.W"])
```

when I looked at the csv file It looked like this:

[image: actual Excel output]

But I want it to be like this:

[image: expected Excel output]

Comment: This looks like an issue with how you opened the file in Excel. How did you do that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when opening a CSV in Microsoft Excel, it sometimes prompts whether to treat the commas as delimiters, and if you select that, it displays the CSV properly. Did you see some prompt like that?

Comment: Provided that the file extension is .csv it works fine on Win11 Excel. It it is called *.txt then you have to tick [x] comma as delimiter in the import wizard. Excel has always been more reliable using space or tab as delimiters (its default) and can be a bit funny with CSV files. Data |> Text to columns gives you another bite that the cherry if a file import loads it as one huge string in column A.

Comment: Which country are you in? Excel has certain regional settings, and the default list separator symbol is part of this. In most European countries for example the default list separator symbol is not a comma but a semicolon instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\scraping\\ddd.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
file = csv.writer(output_file)
file.writerow(["name"])
file.writerow(["age"])
file.writerow(["N.W"])
```

Result:

[image]

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\scraping\\ddd1.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
file = csv.writer(output_file)
file.writerow(["name", "age", "N.W"])  # This will print headers horizontally in the first row
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because it does the same thing op already did.

Comment: @pho If you have noticed, I put a newline method in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer
The problem is not in the code, It's in the excel app itself
this is how to fix it

[Youtube video](https://youtu.be/4ERKOCSB6DI?si=g5EP8eRYvC_uhAFa)

I hope this is helpful for anyone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).